# Sortable List with Rails Namespaces & Railscasts 147 Error: Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I am building a sortable functionality for a join table in Rails. I have 3 models,  Food, User, User_Food.  Food is a prepopulated table of common foods.  A user adds their favorites to User_Food.  I am trying to let the user use JQuery Sortable to reorder their list of favorite foods (using a position column on the User_Food table)...but I'm getting an error.  I am also using Rails Route Namespaces. 
  Again, I am setting the "position" column on the join table (User_Food) NOT in the Food table.

I have been following [Ryan Bates Railscast 147](http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists-revised) and I can get the front end of the drag/drop sortable list to work...but it doesn't save anything.  My trace just shows this:

```
 Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.
```

user.rb

```
has_many :foods, through: :user_foods
has_many :user_foods, dependent: :destroy
```

food.rb

```
has_many :users, through: :user_foods
has_many :user_foods, dependent: :destroy
```

user_food.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :food
```

routes.rb

```
 namespace :profile do
    resources :user_foods do
      collection { post :sort }
    end
  end
```

user_foods_controller.rb

```
  def manage
    @user_foods = UserFood.where(user_id: current_user.id )
  end

  def sort
    params[:user_food].each_with_index do |id, index|
      UserFood.update_all({position: index+1}, {id: id})
    end
    render nothing: true
  end
```

manage.html.slim

```
ul.list-unstyled.pt30  id="user_foods" data-update-url="<%= sort_profile_user_foods_url %>"
  - @user_foods.each do |user_food|
    li
      = user_food.food.name
  = link_to 'add food to list', new_profile_user_food_path
```

js

```
 $('#user_foods').sortable({
  axis: 'y',
  placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
  cursor: 'move',
    update: function() {
      $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'));
    }
  }).disableSelection();
```

**UPDATED**

```
 15:46:13 web.1  |   UserFood Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "user_foods".* FROM "user_foods" WHERE "user_foods"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "user_foods"."position" ASC  [["user_id", 1]]
    15:46:13 web.1  |   Link Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 46, 45, 47, 6, 7)
    15:46:13 web.1  |   Page Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
    15:46:13 web.1  |   Page Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
    15:46:13 web.1  |   Page Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
    15:46:13 web.1  |   Page Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
    15:46:13 web.1  |   Page Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
    15:46:13 web.1  |   Page Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 46]]
    15:46:13 web.1  |   Page Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 45]]
    15:46:13 web.1  |   Page Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 47]]
    15:46:13 web.1  |   Page Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
    15:46:13 web.1  |   Page Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
    15:46:13 web.1  |   Rendered admin/user_foods/edit.html.slim within layouts/admin/application (125.9ms)
    15:46:14 web.1  |   Rendered shared/_admin_header.html.slim (5.3ms)
    15:46:14 web.1  | Completed 200 OK in 213ms (Views: 179.5ms | ActiveRecord: 16.1ms)
    15:46:23 web.1  | Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.
```

Comment: Please add relevant lines from your `log/development.log` file.

Comment: Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.  is the only relevant line I know of

Comment: Well, some lines above and below would definitely help. I.e. your request params and call stack.

Comment: I added the lines before....I don't think there are request params (I'm not sure I know what that means".  I don't have my movable food items within a form...and I'm thinking maybe I need to?

Answer (score 1):

This message is typically triggered by a special character in your query string. Either in the uri, either in the arguments part of the url.

In order to visually find out where a special char is, use your web console to output the parts or the ajax request you are performing:

```
$('#user_foods ul').each(function (i,o) { console.log(o.data('update-url')) });
$('#user_foods ul').each(function (i,o) { console.log(o.sortable('serialize')) });
```

I'm pretty sure that you will find that your serialized string is not as you expected. It seems you are missing to include your record ID in your view. Try this:

```
ul.list-unstyled.pt30  id="user_foods" data-update-url="<%= sort_profile_user_foods_url %>"
  - @user_foods.each do |user_food|
    li id="userfood_#{user_food.id}" # Here, jQuery sortable expect the 
                                     # format "setname_number", and it spits out 
                                     # a hash like "setname[]=number&setname[]=number".

      = user_food.food.name
  = link_to 'add food to list', new_profile_user_food_path
```

You can check [serialize options](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize) which can help you to control the generated string